# Function not being set in time on react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am passing down a function to a react component which seems to render before I receive said function.

In order for me to run it appropriately I do the following in my `render` function:

```
render () {
  if (typeof myFunction === 'function'){
    console.warn('MY FUNCTION IS HERE!', myFunction)
    myFunction()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      My component stuff
    </div>
  )
}
```

Basically when the component first renders, `myFunction` is undefined, so I am doing the check if it is a function before. As it stands, I do get to my `console.warn`, but `myFunction` still is not executed.

Keep in min that it is being set in the app's head through a `script` tag. So it looks something like this:

```
<head>
  {/* Metatags and other scripts in the head */}
  <script src='/static/myFunction.min.js' />
</head>
```

Interestingly enough through the console it does work as expected. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more code? This isn't enough to see what's happening. Especially the part where you say you're passing the function down to the component. How are you doing that exactly?

Comment: It is set in the app's head through a min.js static file. I've updated to OP to include that detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're loading the function into the global space through a script tag, it's likely a race condition. That is, your React component may be rendering before the script with your function is loaded. JavaScript might be hoisting the variable definition, meaning it assigns the variable but does not enter the value until it's ready.

What you see in your console would validate this because by the time you start typing, all code will be executed (probably) and so that function would begin to work.

A way to easily test this would be to add a timeout in the constructor of this component. Set it to something outrageous like 5 seconds, then execute the function. You will likely see that it fires correctly.

As for a solution, it's tricky since you're mucking the lines between React and the outside world. One thing you could do is have the script that imports your function emit an event in the window. Then have your React component listen on that event and cause a re-render (not sure you want to be calling outside functions like this from your render function but I'm sure you have your reasons).

Answer (score 0):

If your script is included in the `<head>` tags without any `async` or `defer` attributes, then it must be loaded before your component renders. The problem might be what `myFunction` is actually doing.

If it manipulates the DOM or anything requiring the page to fully load this might be the problem as the DOM isn't done building when your render function is called, that might explain why you can log your function but it does nothing

Comment: It is set in the app's head through a min.js static file. 
I've updated to OP to include that detail.